# How do I install Ubuntu Studio from a USB Flash Drive?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

So I have the standard Ubuntu 13.10, and I wanted to install Ubuntu studio. The only way I can do that is through a Flash drive, so I downloaded the newest version of Ubuntu studio, and used *Unetbootin* to put the ISO on the Flash drive.

Once that's done, I went to boot from my Flash drive in the BIOS, and all I get is a flashing cursor in the top left. I tried waiting for over an hour and nothing happened. I am not knowledgeable in how any of this works to be honest, I just want to know if there are any solutions?

Comment: I have something unclear, did you booted into the LiveUSB or the problem is on your BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

**if you haven't erased your current version of Ubuntu..**

You can install Ubuntu Studio from a normal Ubuntu opening a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-desktop ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-video linux-rt
```

This is because Ubuntu studio is normal Ubuntu with lots of extra stuff

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this problem on my own laptop-thinkpad T430 -,  just  changed all the bios  setting to  default  and  enable " optimized default " option  under  restart  tap at the most  right

Answer (score -2):

If you're able to see the boot menu (prior to the flashing cursor), hit tab to edit it during the usb-live menu, add the following options after `quiet splash` :

```
noapic noacpi
```

This same issue happened to me with my Lenovo Notebook during my first dual boot installation. I was stuck until until I modified the kernel parameters as mentioned above. Also `nomodeset` can be added to the same boot line, but this should be used as a last resort if the windows manager does not load at first boot, on a live or fresh installed laptop.

Comment: Would you please add `code snippet` sections so its easily readable for what to input into the console?  Please don't use run-on sentences as it makes it difficult to keep track of the instructions for a new user.

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying...  Clearing up your answer would definitely be a pro.